# getColorMode() in Processing

Tags: processing

With

```java
colorMode(HSB);
colorMode(RGB);
```

I can set the color mode.
Apparently the function `getColorMode()` does not exist.
Is there an other soloution to get the color mode?
What I'm trying to do is something like this

```java
int cMode = getColorMode();
colorMode(HSB);
// draw stuff
colorMode(cMode);
```

This code is inside of my class `Track`. I want to draw a recorded GPS track and the hue value should be controled by the speed or the elevation.
Right now I set the color mode back to RGB after I finished drawing. Of course it would be better to set it back to the color mode it was before rather than just assuming, that it already was RGB.

Comment: I just got an email disputing my tag edit (which is very unconventional - this is why we have comments). I will reply here instead: My edits are based off of a StackOverflow Meta decision, referred to on the [Processing tag info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/processing/info). I believe the case for tagging with one or the other, but rarely both, is strongest. So, if you wish to dispute that, go ahead and weigh in on the discussion linked to on that page. That said, I'm also not one to get into edit wars, so if you strongly disagree with a tag edit, feel free to add it back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's take a look at [the source for `PApplet`](https://github.com/processing/processing/blob/master/core/src/processing/core/PApplet.java). That class contains this variable:

```java
public PGraphics g;
```

And here is the `colorMode()` function:

```java
public void colorMode(int mode) {
  if (recorder != null) recorder.colorMode(mode);
  g.colorMode(mode);
}
```

That tells us that `PApplet#colorMode()` is really just a shortcut to `PGraphics#colorMode()`.

So let's look at [the source for `PGraphics`](https://github.com/processing/processing/blob/master/core/src/processing/core/PGraphics.java). The `colorMode()` function from that class eventually leads here:

```java
public void colorMode(int mode,
                        float max1, float max2, float max3, float maxA) {
    colorMode = mode;
    //more code
```

Which leads us to the `colorMode` variable:

```java
/** The current colorMode */
public int colorMode; // = RGB;
```

In other words, to get to the current color mode, you have to go from `PApplet` to its `g` variable, to its `colorMode` variable. If you're in a sketch, it looks like this:

```java
void setup() {
 size(500, 500);
 colorMode(HSB);
}

void draw() {

  background(0);

  if(g.colorMode == RGB){
    println("RGB");
  }
  else if(g.colorMode == HSB){
    println("HSB");
  }
}
```

If you aren't in a sketch, then you'll need to pass in the `PApplet` instance using the `this` keyword.

```java
PApplet mySketch;
int colorMode = mySketch.g.colorMode;
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Kevin's exhaustive answer, you can use [pushStyle()](https://processing.org/reference/pushStyle_.html)/[popStyle()](https://processing.org/reference/pushStyle_.html) calls to isolated drawing styles (including colour spaces):

```
void draw(){
  background(255);
  bars(HSB,0);
  bars(RGB,50);
}
void bars(int colorSpace,int y){
  pushStyle();
  colorMode(colorSpace);
  for(int i = 0 ; i < 10; i++){
    fill(i * 25,255,255);
    rect(10*i,y,10,50);
  }
  popStyle();
}
```

You can run a demo below:

```js
function setup(){
  createCanvas(100,100);
}
function draw(){
  background(255);
  bars(HSB,0);
  bars(RGB,50);
}
function bars(colorSpace,y){
  push();
  colorMode(colorSpace);
  for(var i = 0 ; i < 10; i++){
    fill(i * 25,255,255);
    rect(10*i,y,10,50);
  }
  pop();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```